# PowerShell 'get-ClusterQuorum' output is not showing 'QuorumType' column

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, sql-server-2012, windows-cluster

PowerShell cmdlet `get-ClusterQuorum` output is not showing `QuorumType` column.

Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: What about `get-cluster -name wincluster | get-clusterquorum | ft Cluster, QuorumType -autosize` ?

Comment: You asked the same question on StackOverflow and got an answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224767/powershell-get-clusterquorum-output-is-not-showing-quorumtype-column/25224992#25224992

Answer (score 3):

Copying my answer from [your StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25224767/powershell-get-clusterquorum-output-is-not-showing-quorumtype-column/25224992#25224992):

That is just the normal output for that cmdlet. To see `QuorumType`, you can use these methods:

```powershell
$quorum = Get-ClusterQuorum -Cluster CLUSTER
$quorum | Select-Object *
$quorum.QuorumType

$quorum | Format-Table * # For display only
$quorum | Format-List *  # For display only
```

Many cmdlets control which columns get displayed by default, but the underlying properties are still there and can be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

What works differently?
In Windows Server 2012, you had to determine when to configure a witness, and had to manually adjust the quorum configuration if node membership changed to keep the total number of votes at an odd number. This included every time you added or evicted cluster nodes.
Now, you no longer need to manually adjust the quorum configuration if node membership changes. By default, the cluster determines quorum management options, including the quorum witness.
Windows Server 2012 R2 also includes the new WitnessDynamicWeight cluster common property that you can use to view the quorum witness vote.
To view the property value, start Windows PowerShell as an administrator, and then enter the following command:
(Get-Cluster).WitnessDynamicWeight
A value of "0" indicates that the witness does not have a vote. A value of "1" indicates that the witness has a vote.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265972(v=ws.11).aspx